# How to remove the PDF/A standard of PDF document using Apache PDFbox API?

Tags: apache, pdf, merge, pdfbox

I am using the PDFMERGERUTILITY class to merge multiple files  using APAchePDF box API.
The generated merged document follows a PDF/A standard, how to remove this standard using PDFbox API?

Comment: *The generated merged document follows a PDF/A standard* - I doubt that. Probably it claims to do so but most likely it doesn't.

Comment: No it was follows PDF/A standard, our client not able to edit that document with adobe acrobat professional.

Comment: Point your client to http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2011/05/how-to-remove-pdfa-information-from-a-file/ which explains how to disable PDF/A in Acrobat X and XI.